# SOOT class loading -- what is a 'level'?

Tags: java, class, classloader, code-generation, soot

From [here](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Class-loading-in-Soot):

> The design of coffi requires that in order to bring some class C up to level N, you must first bring all classes that C references up to level N-1. In order to know which classes C references, you need to bring C up to level N-1.

What are these "levels"?

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, Soot can load classes only to a certain level, e.g. only loading signatures but not bodies. Details can be seen in the class SootClass.